@JavascriptInterface in webview not work with annotation @Compose
I want to pass text to my text UI while use @JavascriptInterface in background, for this I do it using viewModel(). But for that need to put an annotation @Compose, and @JavascriptInterface stops working with that annotation
class getHtmlListener(private val webView: WebView, private val mContext: Context){
@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
@JavascriptInterface
fun getHtml(html: String?) {
           
        here jsoup parse text and pass to ui every 5 seconds//
       }

